# В чём проблема кода

Tags: javascript, html

Написал код чтобы он при вводе двух чисел сравнивал их и говорил какое число больше или  они равны, но текст с результатом не выводится.
 В чём проблема?

JS код:

```
    function compNumb()
var a,b,d;
a = document.getElementById("i1").value;
a = parseInt(a);
b = document.getElementById("i2").value;
b = parseInt(b);
d = document.getElementById("out")
if (a>b)
    {
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "Первое число больше второго!";
    }
else if (a<b)
    {
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "Второе число больше.";
    }
else
    {
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "Числа одинаковы.";
    }
```

html код:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="1.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Введите числа для сравнения! <input type="text" id="i1"></p>
   <p><input type="text" id="i2"></p>
   <p id="out">ТУТ</p>
   <hr>
   <button onclick="compNumb()">Сверяю</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Код принято приводить в вопросе, а не делать ссылку на внешние ресурсы. Это удобнее - не надо никуда переходить, к тому же нет риска, что со временем ссылка станет недействительной.

Comment: Учту. Что касательно вопроса, в чём проблема?

Comment: @ДаняБрандт касательно вопроса проблема в том, что в нем нет Вашего кода - под вопросом ссылка "править"

Comment: Исправил. Что дальше?

Comment: Для начала исправьте ошибки синтаксиса

Answer (score 4):

У вас ошибка в синтаксисе, отсутствуют скобки.

```js
function compNumb() { //скобка
  var a, b, d;
  a = document.getElementById("i1").value;
  a = parseInt(a);
  b = document.getElementById("i2").value;
  b = parseInt(b);
  d = document.getElementById("out");
  
  if (a>b) {
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML="Первое число больше второго!";
  }
  else if (a<b) {
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML="Второе число больше.";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML="Числа одинаковы.";
  }
  
}//скобка
```

```html
<p>Введите числа для сравнения! <input type="text" id="i1"></p>
<p><input type="text" id="i2"></p>
<p id="out">ТУТ</p>
<hr>
<button onclick="compNumb()">Сверяю</button>
```